# Doing a while into a switch

Tags: c, while-loop, switch-statement

i wanna to do a multiplication table, 
where the user choose the number and after show up the table.
but in my code, the while dosen't work inside the switch, why? 
ex:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

int x,y=10;

printf("Welcome!\n");
printf("choose a number for multiplication table \n");
scanf("%i",&x);


switch(x){

    case '1':
        while(y)
        {

            printf(" %i * %i  = %i \n",x,y,x*y);
            y--;


        }
    };break;    
}
}
```

Comment: What's your break doing outside of the switch?

Comment: Your case is the ascii value for the character 1 not the numeric value 1. Is this intended?

Comment: Also, the switch isn't going to work very well, comparing the character "1" to a numeric value.

Comment: ow, sorry, the right is :  
switch(x){

case '5':
while(y){
printf(" %i * %i  = %i \n",x,y,x*y);
y--;
}break; 

}
the character 1 is right but i change now for 5, the result must be :
5*10
5*9
5*8
5*7 
...

Answer (score 4):

You have an extra }

```
case '1':
    while(y)
    {

        printf(" %i * %i  = %i \n",x,y,x*y);
        y--;


    }
};break; // This break is outside of your switch
```

Also, you're switching on a character value of 1, not the integer value of 1.  You should change the `case` to match, as well.

Comment: now the break is inside but still dont work :\

Comment: @AnaIzabelA.Jacobsen As I mentioned, you also need to fix the `'1'` and change it to `1`...

Answer (score 2):

`'1'` is not the `int` value `1` (but the character literal `'1'` and has an `int` value of `49`) so I suspect it is not entering that case in the switch. Change the case label to the integer literal `1`:

```
case 1:
```

Check the return value of `scanf()` to ensure an `int` was read and the subsequent code is not processing `x` unitialised:

```
if (1 == scanf("%i", &x))
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C++ switch-case syntax:

```
switch ( x) {

  case 1 : //x is an integer

    while(y)
    {
        printf(" %i * %i  = %i \n",x,y,x*y);
        y--;
    }
    break; //Inside the case


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Despite of an extra brace, there is a problem with the way you compare input value with options in switch statement. In the following line:

```
scanf("%i",&x);
```

compiler is informed that program expects here an integer value, so when user type in 1 on stdin, 0x01 is stored in x variable. Unfortunately, here:

```
case '1':
```

x variable is compared with '1' (ASCII character) which equals 0x31. So your case statement should look like:

```
case 1:
```

Of course you can use ASCII characters in case statements. You could modify program to treat input as char data type:

```
scanf("%c",&x);
```

Then, 0x31 is stored in x variable and comparing it with '1' makes sense. However, you have to remember to convert x to int value to not break your program's functionality:

```
x -= 0x30;
```

First approach is definitely more convenient.